# Are Asian fonts broken in iOS 13?

Tags: ios, qt, fonts, cjk

We're building an iPad app with Qt 5.12.6 that supports Japanese in its UI. For several releases, switching the device to Japanese has worked, our text displays fine.

But with iOS 13, most of the characters are displaying incorrectly, with simple bars as placeholders for the characters.

Anyone having issues with iOS 13 and Asian fonts? We're using 13.3, specifically. Thank you in advance!

Comment: THANK YOU, Frank Osterfeld!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by a change in iOS 13, Qt 5.13.2 and 5.14.0 contain a fix. In the Qt Bugtracker, the issue is tracked as [QTBUG-77467](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-77467). If you can't upgrade Qt, the ticket also mentions a workaround, which fixed the issue for me:

```
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

// iOS 13 bug fix
#if defined(Q_OS_IOS)
    QFont f("Helvetica");
    app.setFont(f);
#endif
```